# Error when running WordPress on new server

Tags: php, cakephp, wordpress

I've just upload a WordPress project into a web server. Everything went fine with the exception of the User-Photo plugin. The problem I'm having is that its doesn't seems to find the basedir path. This is the error:

> Upload error: Unable to place the user photo at: /var/www/clients/client2/web4/web/arsoblog/wp-content/uploads/userphoto/1.jpg

First of all, I don't know where this path is. Even on the local server, where the site is working good, is using the exact same path, which I can't find.

Maybe someone of you knows what could have changed from one server to the other. By the way, the blog is inside another site in the web server, which is developed using CakePHP.

EDIT --- I'm having the same problem with all the uploads!

Comment: Ok, but how can I get to the solution?. Can the permissions being set from inside the script, or is something I have to do from inside the server?

Comment: If you have root access to the server change the user who owns the uploads directory to be the same as the web server that way the server can always write to that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your upload directory. When we develop the WordPress site in localhost, the default upload directory will be point to your localhost only. When you move to online server, this directory path will not change.

To override this do the following steps:

1. Login to your cPanel/control Panel
2. Go to phpMyadmin
3. Select your database.
4. Go to wp_options table
5. On the second page (around 58th row) Edit 'upload_path'(For the first time this row may be blank).
6. Give your correct directory.Eg: /home/username/public_html/folder-name/wp-content/uploads

Change "username" and "folder-name". Username is usually the username you use to login to cPanel, or your domain’s control panel. Folder-name is used for the sites hosted in subfolders. If you hosted the site in root folder, remove it.

Here is a detailed tutorial [How to move wordpress to a new server or host](http://blog.triphp.com/how-to/how-to-move-wordpress-to-a-new-server-or-host.html).

If you already used WordPress uploader in localhost, you need to do a search in wp_posts table and replace your localhost reference to your live site's reference. There are some plugin available to do these search and replace in database. [Check this one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-and-replace/)

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

777 permissions are dangerous and not the correct fix for the issue. You will get hacked with 777 permissions. See [Hardening WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress)

Comment: Ok, yes, you are right. I was just reading about it. And I also have another problem with that solution: any new folders created by the program have the 755 permission, so the error continued.

Comment: Your account and apache ownership of the files and folders is wrong. Tell you host to fix it or find another host.

Answer (score 1):

For solving this problem you have follow some step,

*Login to your cPanel/control Panel

*Go to phpMyadmin

*Select your database.

*Go to wp_options table

*On the second page (around 58th row) Edit 'upload_path'

*Give your correct directory.Eg: /home/username/public_html/folder-name/wp-content/uploads
then you shift your server [See tutorial](http://wordpress.visitmix.com/development/installing-wordpress-on-sql-server)

for more
http://www.techyv.com/questions/error-when-running-wordpress-new-server